# Computing an intergral on a sphere

Tags: integration

I'm struggling with the following integral:
$$\int \limits_{S_t(x)} y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 \, dA(y),$$
where $S_t(x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^3: \lvert y - x\rvert = t \}$.

I understand the integral above as average value of the integrand over $S_t(x)$. However I don't know how to compute it.

I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Have you studied the Stokes formula ?

Comment: @DIdier_, no. Can you provide me a link or something, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Here, it would say that your integral in the same as an intergral on the ball of radius $t$ and center $x$ of another function. It's the generalization of $\int_a^b f = F(b) - F(a)$

Comment: Here you can just use the Otrogradsky formulation, that is $\int_S (F\cdot n) = \int_B (\nabla\cdot F)$. You then have to find what $F$ is.

Comment: @DIdier_ is $F$ the antiderivative of my integrand?

Comment: No, $F$ should be a vector valued function and $n$ stands for the normal to your sphere. For simple purpose I take $x$ as the origin of the space, so $y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2 = || y||^2 = ||y||\times y \cdot n$ where $n$ is the normal to your sphere. Thus $F(y) = ||y|| \times y$ here. Edit : sorry I used the notation $F$ in two different comments but they do not refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating the integral we get that

$$\int_{S_t(x)} y^2\:dA(y) = \int_{S_t(0)} (y+x)^2 \:dA(y)$$

Then use the fact that $dA(y) = t^2d\Omega$

$$\int_{S_t(0)} y^2+2y\cdot x + x^2 \:dA(y) = \int_{S^2} t^4 + x^2t^2\:d\Omega + \int_{S_t(0)} 2y\cdot x \:dA(y) = 4\pi t^2(x^2+t^2)$$

where the second integral vanished because the integrand was odd.

Comment: What does $y^2$ mean here?

Comment: @Hendrra the dot product of $y$ with itself.

Comment: Thanks! So can I also conclude that for example $\int \limits_{S_t(x)} y_3 dA(y) = 0$? Because the integrand is odd?

Comment: @Hendrra no, because the sphere is not centered at the origin.

Comment: Can you give me a tip to deal with that integral too, please?

Comment: @Hendrra translate it.

Comment: That's a good idea! I do get two integrals, one of them vanishes and the second is equal to $4 \pi xt$. Thank you!

Comment: @Hendrra no that is not correct. It should be $4\pi t^2x_3$

Comment: Why is so? Am I do subtract only $x_3$?

Comment: @Hendrra because that's how vector addition works, component wise.

Comment: That's true. However in that situation I won't have my sphere centered at the origin, will I?

Comment: @Hendrra ...you wouldn't? Is it not true that $$\int_{S_t(x)} f(y_1,y_2,y_3)\:dA(y)  = \int_{S_t(0)} f(y_1+x_1,y_2+x_2,y_3+x_3)\:dA(y)$$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108224/discussion-between-hendrra-and-ninad-munshi).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

With substitutions $y_1 = x_1 + t\sin \phi \cos \theta$,
$y_2 = x_2 + t\sin \phi \sin \theta$ and $y_3 = x_3 + t\cos \phi$
for $\phi \in [0, \pi]$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.
Then $\mathrm{d} A(y) = t^2 \sin\phi \ \mathrm{d}\phi \ \mathrm{d}\theta$.
See: http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes02/v9.pdf

We have
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} 
[(x_1 + t\sin \phi \ \cos \theta)^2 + (x_2 + t\sin \phi\ \sin \theta)^2 + (x_3 + t\cos \phi)^2]
t^2 \sin\phi \ \mathrm{d}\theta \ \mathrm{d}\phi\\
&= 4\pi t^2 (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + t^2).
\end{align}